# How to dynamically repeat for all children of a JSON array, that may have children (PHP)

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to code a website that takes the comments of a Reddit page and shows them. However, the comments have replies, and I want to show those too, but a comment can have none, one or more replies, and those replies can have replies. Is there a way to repeat the same code for all of the replies with minor differences (indentation)? I'm using the reddit json feature, and am getting the JSON from something like here: https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/dln0o3/foldinghome_and_pcmr_team_up_use_your_pc_to_help/.json. 
I have:

```
$url = ('https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/dln0o3/foldinghome_and_pcmr_team_up_use_your_pc_to_help/.json');
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

$comment_array = array_slice($obj[1]['data']['children'], 0, 50);
echo '<div class="comments">';
foreach ($comment_array as $c) {
    echo "<p>(".$c['data']['author'].") ". $c['data']['score'] . " Points<br>".$c['data']['body']."</p>";
    if (!($c['data']['replies'] == "")) {
        $r1_array = $c['data']['replies']['data']['children'];
        foreach ($r1_array as $r1) {
            echo "<p>    (".$r1['data']['author'].") ". $r1['data']['score'] . " Points<br>    ".$r1['data']['body']."</p>";
            if (!($r1['data']['replies'] == "")) {
                $r2_array = $r1['data']['replies']['data']['children'];
                foreach ($r2_array as $r2) {
                    echo "<p>        (".$r2['data']['author'].") ". $r1['data']['score'] . " Points<br>        ".$r2['data']['body']."</p>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This produces the desired result, with replies to replies and such. However, it's a bit messy, and if there is a really long reply chain, it won't catch it. Is there a way to make it repeat somehow or should I just copy and paste it a bunch of times?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Okay, look, let's trim the fat and try to make your question clear, minimal, and verifiable.  Remove the first three lines in your snippet -- because you aren't having any issue receiving the file contents. (let's not call your input `$obj` when it is actually an array)  Show us a sufficiently large sample input (`$array`) -- it needs to have enough replies and whatever so that the data is realistic, but we don't want an array that has 1000 elements.  You have shown us your code and that is great.  Finally show us your current output and show us your desired output.  Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a concept called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

The basic idea is that a function will call itself as many times as needed (as opposed to using a fixed number of loops).

Something like this:

```
<?php

function output($data, $level = 0) {
  $spaces = str_repeat(' &nbsp;', $level);
  foreach ($data as $post) {
    echo "<p>(".$spaces.$post['data']['author'].") ". $post['data']['score'] . " Points<br>".$post['data']['body']."</p>\r\n";
    if ($post['data']['replies']) {

      // Notice that we are calling the function again, this time increasing the level
      // This is the "recursive" part of the function
      output($post['data']['replies']['data']['children'], $level + 1);

    }
  }
}

$url = ('https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/dln0o3/foldinghome_and_pcmr_team_up_use_your_pc_to_help/.json');
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$comment_array = array_slice($data[1]['data']['children'], 0, 50);
output($comment_array);

?>
```